# Return the highest SUM value of all donors by designations

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, row-number

I have the following script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GIFT_ID, GIFT_DESG, SUM(GIFT_AMT)
FROM GIFT_TABLE
GROUP BY GIFT_ID, GIFT_DESG
```

It will return something like this:

```
GIFT_ID         GIFT_DESG      SUM(GIFT_AMT)
      1                A               25
      1                B              500
      1                C               75
      2                A              100
      2                B              200
      2                C              300
      ...
```

My desired outcome is:

```
GIFT_ID         GIFT_DESG      SUM(GIFT_AMT)
      1                B           500
      2                C           300
```

How would I do that?

Possibly row_number() right? I think it's something with the summing of gift amounts by designation that is throwing me off.

Thank you.

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hi jarlh, Oracle 11g.

Comment: You don't have a "script", you have a query. (Is it in a script? You didn't show that.) Not every code snippet is a "script".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your DBMS support `ROW_NUMBER` window function you can try to make row number by `GIFT_ID` order by `SUM(GIFT_AMT)` then get `rn = 1` row.

```
SELECT t1.GIFT_ID,t1.GIFT_DESG,t1.GIFT_AMT 
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GIFT_ID ORDER BY GIFT_AMT DESC) rn
    FROM (
      SELECT  GIFT_ID, GIFT_DESG, SUM(GIFT_AMT) GIFT_AMT
      FROM GIFT_TABLE
      GROUP BY GIFT_ID, GIFT_DESG
    ) t1
) t1
where rn =1
```

**Note**

You already use `GROUP BY` the `DISTINCT` keyword is no sense, you can remove it from your query.

---

Here is a sample

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   GIFT_ID int,
   GIFT_DESG varchar(5),
  GIFT_AMT int
);


insert into t values (1,'A' ,25);
insert into t values (1,'B' ,500);
insert into t values (1,'C' ,75);
insert into t values (2,'A' ,100);
insert into t values (2,'B' ,200);
insert into t values (2,'C' ,300);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.GIFT_ID,t1.GIFT_DESG,t1.GIFT_AMT 
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GIFT_ID ORDER BY GIFT_AMT DESC) rn
    FROM T t1
) t1
where rn =1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac9e8/1/0)**:

```
| GIFT_ID | GIFT_DESG | GIFT_AMT |
|---------|-----------|----------|
|       1 |         B |      500 |
|       2 |         C |      300 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with no subquery:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES GIFT_ID, GIFT_DESG, SUM(GIFT_AMT)
FROM GIFT_TABLE
GROUP BY GIFT_ID, GIFT_DESG
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GIFT_ID ORDER BY SUM(GIFT_AMT) DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also like this

```
WITH t as
   SELECT GIFT_ID, GIFT_DESG, SUM(GIFT_AMT) AS GIFT_AMT
   FROM GIFT_TABLE
   GROUP BY GIFT_ID, GIFT_DESG)
SELECT  GIFT_ID, 
   max(GIFT_DESG) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY GIFT_AMT), 
   max(GIFT_AMT) GIFT_AMT
FROM T
GROUP BY GIFT_ID;
```